# UPDATE PRODUCT IMAGE IN PHP/MYSQL WOOCOMMERCE

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo las imagenes ya subidas al directorio de wp-content/uploads/2020/11/qhweuhwjkallwdkawkdmlaw.png

En una tabla, tengo el sku del articulo y la url de la imagen,

Como puedo insertar la imagen a ese producto directamente en la base de datos o alguna otra funcion para hacerlo en un archivo .php direfente a `functions.php`

Tengo este codigo, pero no logro actualizar aun las imagenes de las mismas

````
<?php
// conexion a la base de datos
require('mysqli.php');
// empezamos a leer los datos de la tabla
$qMain = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM product_imagenes;");
// abrimos el documento para escribir las imagenes
$fp = fopen("imagenes.txt", "w+");
// empezamos el recorrido por filas
foreach($qMain['data'] as $r) {

    // seleccionamos el producto segun el art_codigo
    $query = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM tienda_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = ".$r->art_codigo." ORDER BY post_id DESC;");

    // extraemos el id del post
    $post_id = $query['data'][0]->post_id;
    // codigo de articulo
    $art_codigo = $r->art_codigo;
    // imagen del producto
    $imagenes = $r->imagenes;

// actualizar datos segun criterios de valor y post id
ExecuteReader("UPDATE `tienda_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = ".$imagenes." WHERE `tienda_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_wp_attached_file' AND `tienda_postmeta`.`post_id` = ".$post_id.";");


// agregamos la columna dentro del documento
fputs($fp, '{"post_id": '.$post_id.', "art_codigo": '.$art_codigo.', "imagenes": '.$imagenes.'}');

// borramos registro de la tabla segun art_codigo
ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM product_imagenes WHERE art_codigo = *?*;", array(
                $r->art_codigo
));
  
// fin del recorrido
};

// cerramos el documento imagenes.txt
fclose($fp); 

// imprimimos un Mensaje de exito
echo "<pre>";
echo '{

     "Response": "Imagenes Sincronizadas Con Exito"

}';
?>```
````

Comment: si tenes sku y url lo mas simple, seguro y rápido es armar un csv y realizar un import que refresque la imagen según el SKU, las imágenes son attachments  y cambiar el url desde la db puede romper o fallar las diferentes variaciones de tamaños que se crean ( thumb, medium, large ). los títulos de las columnas del csv deberían ser SKU e images, aunque en el mapeo de importación te permite elegir otros nombres de columnas. siempre hacer pruebas en una instalación diferente para no romper nada

Comment: La idea es hacerlo de manera automatica, ya que va integrada a la erp del cliente, pero la solucion ya esta hecha.

Comment: De igual manera muchas gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: para integración directa [fijate la api](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#update-a-product) se maneja con id de producto pero lo podes obtener por sku haciendo un query con parámetros: [`un ejemplo en php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15661#issuecomment-506981886)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví el inconveniente con las funciones nativas de WooCommerce, sin tener que recurrir a la actualización mediante base de datos:

La solución fue la siguiente:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
require('mysqli.php');
$qMain = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM product_imagenes;");
require('../wp-load.php');
require_once('../wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
foreach($qMain['data'] as $r) {
    $query = ExecuteReader("SELECT * FROM tienda_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = ".$r->art_codigo.";");
        $post_parent_id = $query['data'][0]->post_id;
    if($query['count'] == 0) {
        // borramos registro de la tabla segun art_codigo
ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM product_imagenes WHERE art_codigo = *?*;", array(
                $r->art_codigo
));
    } else {
 
            delete_post_meta($post_parent_id, '_wp_attached_file');
            add_post_meta($post_parent_id, '_wp_attached_file', $r->imagenes_src, true);
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $upload_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/tienda/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/';
            $file             = array();
            $file['error']    = '';
            $file['tmp_name'] = $r->imagenes_name;
            $file['name']     = $r->imagenes_name;
            $file['type']     = 'image/png';
            $file['size']     = filesize($upload_path . $r->imagenes_name);
            $file_return = wp_handle_sideload($file, array('test_form' => false));
            $filename = $r->imagenes_name;
            $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/png',
            'post_title' => $filename,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'guid' => $r->imagenes_src
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $r->imagenes_src);
            set_post_thumbnail($post_parent_id, $attach_id);
            ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM product_imagenes WHERE art_codigo = *?*;", array(
                $r->art_codigo
            ));
        
    }
};
echo "<pre>";
echo '{

     "Response": "Imagenes Sincronizadas Con Exito"

}';
?>
```

Comment: si se rompe la cadena de plugins y no te genera las thumbnails ( o la version webp de algunos plugins ) agregale un [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) seguido de un [`wp_update_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_attachment_metadata/) justo luego del 'wp_insert_attachment' /1

Comment: si la tabla de donde sacas la info a sincronizar está en la misma db, y querés hacer un cron tal vez te convenga fijarte la alternativa de correr el php con [`wp cli eval-file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/) con parámetros extra podés incluir/excluir plugins o el theme si notas que algo sale raro en el import ( o consume mucha memoria ) /2